# spring boot + redis cache + @Cacheable works for some methods and not others

Tags: java, spring, caching, redis, spring-boot

I am using spring boot with redis for a cache, to improve application performance by reducing querying the RDBMS system.
It works, as it caches the methods of another controller accurately but it does not cache the controller below:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Cacheable("findByTaxOfficeId")
    private TaxPayerNameResponse findByTaxOfficeId(@RequestParam(required = true, value = "uid") String taxOfficeId) {
        StampDutyOffice stampDutyOffice = null;
```

The configuration looks the same for the working spring boot controller.
A sample of a cached Controller method that works properly can be found below:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/stampdutyoffice", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Cacheable("getTaxPayerNameByTinIdOrJtbIdReqParam2")
    public TaxPayerNameResponse2 getTaxPayerNameByTinIdOrJtbIdReqParam2(@RequestParam(required = true, value = "uid") String tinIdOrJtbIdStampDutyOffice) {
        return getTaxPayerNameByTinIdOrJtbId2(tinIdOrJtbIdStampDutyOffice);
    }
```

What could be the issue please?
Thanks in advance for helping out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your findByTaxOfficeId method is *private*, make it *public*

Answer (score 7):

For some Spring annotations you should obey two rules for annotated methods to be sure that it works:

- it should be a PUBLIC method
- it should be NOT called from within the same class

Same situation with @Async for example